# mysql db design for admin customized app

Tags: mysql, database

I am planning to design db for a website. We have different screens in our website. Each screen should have unique id and each screen will be of different type. Info related to screen should store in its type table. How Can i do that?

My plan is use screens table with below fields

**Screens**
screen_id
screen_type
screen_type_table_name

**Home_screen**
home_screen_id
screen_id
language
content1
content2
home_screen_field1
home_screen_field2

**aboutus_screen**
aboutus_screen_id
screen_id
language
content1
content2
about_us_field1
about_us_field2

Relation of the above two tables is 1 to many(screens table to type table). One screen may have many records in type table (in different languages).

Problems here is, I cannot query the data in single query. As I am storing the table name in the screens table.

Can anybody suggest best db design here?

**[EDIT]**
I cannot store the info in same table..

**Reasons:**
1) language constraint
2) I need to maintain revision of each content
3) Each screen of different type. So fields will be different for each type. No of fields vary for each type also.
4) I cannot serialize the data too (as I need search kind of facility)

**Req**
With Screen Id, I should be able to fetch the content in single query. Please give me some suggestions.
Thanks In advance

Thanks
Venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Home_screen and Aboutus_screen tables are exactly the same. You could try it like this:

```
//screens\\
screen_id (PK)
language (PK)
type_id (FK)
content1
content2

//screen_types\\
screen_type_id (PK)
screen_type_name
```

As you see there is a double Primary Key on the screens table and you keep track of the type of page by the Foreign key to the screen_types, if that's necessary.

Comment: I have updated my question. Actually each screen type will have different fields.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't put them in the same table, sorry. Except when you want the about_us_field1 to be e.g. an INTEGER and the home_screen_field1 e.g. a VARCHAR. If they are of the same data type, you should still put them  in one table.

Comment: right, But the home_screen will contain many other fields specific to that home screen. I just mentioned two fields. It would be different type also and no of fields for each screen will vary. So I cannot put those in screens table (assume type tables as different objects, I just mentioned two type tables. But there are many other types)

Comment: If you really want to split it up in a table per page, maybe there is some way to do it with a subquery. But I've never done anything like that. But how do you determine which screen_id you want to query for? Where does that id come from?

Comment: Yes. But how do you determine which id you should load on each page?

Comment: yes, That is the problem here. 

My solution needs 2 queries. Say I want to load screen_id=2; First I will query the screens table and gets the screen info. Now I know the info is in which table(from scree_type_table field). Say it is home_Screen, Now I will query home_screen table with screen_id (home_screen table will contain screen_id) based on user languages.

Comment: Yes. I see. But how do you choose to load for example screen_id=2 ? Where does that 2 come from? Why 2 and not e.g. 3? Is it hard-coded?

Comment: Each screen will have button. When user clicks button, it will open another screen. Admin will configure which screen to open.

Comment: You could try not only to configure the id of the page to load, but also the type, so that you immediately know which table to query.

Comment: but how can i query the data in single query?

Comment: What I meant was that you find a way to eliminate the screens table. If your admin could configure a button to link to a certain id, you should not only save the id, but also the table where the page is. e.g. Button A leads to screen_id=2 in home_screens and button B leads to screen_id=3 in about_us. In that way, you already know in which table you should look, so you only need one query. If that doesn't suit you I don't really know what will. I don't think the extra query is a big problem though.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have posted here to know whether there is any better design. I should thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Even though eliminating screens table is not possible here, but your idea is good for these kind of problems :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep all the screens in one table? You should do something like

**Screens**
id,
language,
content1,
content2,
etc

Then just query the table when you want a page. I'm not sure why you have separated them as it is, is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: yes, I cannot store the info in same table..
**reasons**
language constraint  
I need to maintain revision of each content  
Each screen of different type. SO fields will be different for each type.
I cannot serialize the data too (as I need search kind of facility)